# Entity Framework conflict while adding row

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity

I am using entity framework code first approach.

I can add record, Update record, but while adding new record I am getting this ERROR message

```
"Conflicting changes to the role 'SaleCellBase_column_Target' of the relationship 'Sale.Classes.SaleCellBase_column' have been detected."
```

How can I solve this?

```
I have tree class;

SaleRow sale = new SaleRow (sheet, "Sales", "A-sale", Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.Empty);
sheet.rows.Add(sale);
SaleColumn col = new SaleColumn(sheet, i);
sheet.columns.Add(col);
dbContext.Sale.Add(row);
dbContext.SaveChanges();


 for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
 {
     SaleCell cell = new SaleCell(row, sheet.columns[j], demoSheet);

     sheet.cells.Add(cell);
     row.cells.Add(cell);
      sheet.columns[j].cells.Add(cell);
 }
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
 treeList1.DataSource = sheet.rows;
```

This code run and I show my record treeList. While adding new row

```
 saleRow=sheet.rows.ToList();

 for (int k = 0; k < sheet.rows.Count; k++)
 {
 SaleRow saleRowControl = con.SaleRow.FirstOrDefault(p => p.hierId==dataRow.hierId);

 if(saleRowControl==null)
    dbContext.SaleRow.Add(saleRow[k]);
 }
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get error.

Comment: Can you show us any code?

Comment: Yes, I showed some code.Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you are trying to add a record with a foreign key that allready exists or trying to add a value in de identifier column while the identifier will automaticly be filled by the database.

Have you set your keys properly on both sides?
Can you post the code that goes wrong?

Comment: That's true but I only have 36 reputation so I'am not allowed yet to comment on a question.. :$

Comment: Is salesRow[k] of type SaleRow?

Comment: Yes, List<SaleRow> salesRow = new List<SaleRow>();

Comment: When I debug this code saleRow[k] has values. but dbContext.SaleRow.Add(saleRow[k) not working.

Comment: You should check your foreign keys. I suppose the record doesn't exist in the context? If you add it to the database manualy with the same values, does that work?

Comment: I suppose the record doesn't exist in the context? I cant understand it. Can you explain it?

Comment: Sorry, I mean does it exist in the database (context)

Comment: If my foreign keys wrong, how can add in first time. When I show treelist and user insert a record, I cant add this. But saleRow[k] when I debug it is not null.

Comment: No it doesnt because I check row Id in database.